# setting variables from another form

Tags: parameter-passing, command-line-interface

What is the 'smart and direct' way to set some Form variable values from another sub-form.
Say I have mainForm that contains myVar (network port number for example) and settingsButton which when clicked shows another form settingsForm that aims to set myVar....
since settingsForm can't return things other than DialogResult how can I achieve it.
I used to implement it by passing the mainForm instant to settingsForm in its constructor to access its data members as follows:

```
//////mainForm.h:
#include "settingsForm.h"
...
ref class mainForm: puplic Form
{
puplic:
    int myVar;
private: void settingsButton_Click(Object^  sender, EventArgs^  e)
{
    (gcnew settingsForm(this))->ShowDialog();
}
...
};
....
////////settingsForm.h
...
ref class mainForm; //forward declaration to avoid circular dependency
ref class settingsForm:public Form
{
mainForm^ mf;
settingsForm(mainForm form)
{
    ....
    mf=form;
}
void okButton_click(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e);  //definition in the cpp file
...
};
///////settingsForm.cpp
...
void settingsForm::okButton_click(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
{
    mf->myVar= someValue;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an event or a shared area to exchange data between them.
But I think your own way is simple and better.
Why are you looking for another way?

Comment: thank you for reply!
I just wonder if there's any way to avoid rewrite both cpp and h files by for example returning the values from settingsForm.

Comment: You could pass reference of your fields to settingsForm, in this way, there is no dependency between forms but I think you must use an event for changing this value, it is better.